# printing key and value of json objects

Tags: jquery, json

i have 2 external json files and i have to read data from those files using the key and value. my application is not dependent on the obj.name etc. Please help me to print these values.

Planets.json

```
 {
"Planets": [
  { "name": "Mercury",
    "color": "Orange",
    "distance": "57.91 km",
    "radius": "2340 km",
    "year": "0.24085 Earth",
    "day": "88 days",
    "mass": "0.054 Earth"
  },

  { "name": "second",
    "color": "Orange",
    "distance": "57.91 km",
    "radius": "2340 km",
    "year": "0.24085 Earth",
    "day": "88 days",
    "mass": "0.054 Earth"
  }
```

}

Airports.json

```
    {
"Airports": [
  {
    "listing": "East 34th Street Heliport",
    "iata": "TSS",
    "type": "Heliport",
    "size": "Tiny"
  }
```

}

and this is the code i am trying.

```
              $.ajax({
                url:"planets.json",
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(json){
                    $.each(json, function(key, value){
                        console.log(key + ": " + value);
                    });
                }

            });
```

and i am getting this out put in console

Planets: [object Object]

Answer (score 5):

Get the nested object using `json.Planets[0]` and iterate over it.

```
$.each(json.Planets[0], function(key, value){
    console.log(key + ": " + value);
});
```

---

**UPDATE 1 :** If the object only contains one property then you can get it using **[`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)** and do the same as the previous example.

```
$.each(json[Object.keys(json)[0]][0], function(key, value){
    console.log(key + ": " + value);
});
```

---

**UPDATE 2 :**
In case there are multiple properties then use **[`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)** method twice.

```
$.each(json,function(k, v){
    $.each(v[0], function(key, value){
        console.log(key + ": " + value);
    });
})
```

---

**UPDATE 3 :** If you have nested array with multiple objects then use an additional **[`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** method to iterate it.

```
json[Object.keys(json)[0]].forEach(function(v){
    $.each(v, function(key, value){
        console.log(key + ": " + value);
    });
});
```

---

**UPDATE 3 :** If your JSON consists multiple properties with nested multiple array element do the combination of above methods.

```
$.each(json,function(k, v){
    v.forEach(function(v1){  
        $.each(v1, function(key, value){
            console.log(key + ": " + value);
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: if i change the my file name planets to airports then i have to modify everything

Comment: If you iterate over your top-level object (json), you can get the keys: Planets, Airports, etc.

Comment: for example if have 3 palnets and print those one by one ?

Comment: @SaqibSaqib : glad to help :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118589/discussion-between-pranav-c-balan-and-saqib-saqib).

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, use below option

```
$.each(json, function(key, value) {
  $.each(value[0], function(k, val) {
    console.log(k + ":" + val);
  });
});
```

Codepen- http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/GqGVGd

Answer (score 0):

You can use a double each so that its not depended on the name "airports"

```
$.each(json, function(objectTitle, objects){
    console.log('List of ' + objectTitle + ':');
    $.each(objects, function(objectKey, objectValue){
        console.log(objectKey + ':' +  objectValue);
    });
});
```